# Functions Mapping Integers to Zero?

Tags: functions, roots, integers

I am looking for functions such that:

$z∈$ **Z** ⇔   $f(z)=0$

That is to say, functions that map from **Z** to the zero set.

One example is $f(z)=\sin(πz)$.

EDIT: To narrow the possible group of functions, the following conditions must be met:

1. $f(z)$ must be a continuous, differentiable function (it may not be a piecewise-defined function)
2. The function must be expressible in terms of other elementary, special or algebraic functions.

Specifically, I am looking for functions that are easy to analyze and manipulate. The function should not be trivial.  This was a question posed to me by my teacher; sine was the example function. I am looking for further examples.

Comment: Can you be more precise ? There are infinitely many such trivial functions (take $f(x\notin\Bbb{Z})=a$ and $f(z\in\Bbb{Z})=0$ for any $a\neq0$)

Comment: Then you also have $(1+|g(z)|)\sin \pi z$ for any function $g$. You haven't really specified the domain, but this will work for the obvious ones

Comment: Are you looking for continuous such functions, for example?

Comment: Or take any non-zero function $g(x)$ and let $f(x) = sin(\pi x)g(x)$.

Comment: @Théophile This also works for any $h(x)$ satisfying the property you can let $f(x) = h(x)g(x)$.

Comment: @David: That gives no greater generality because any $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ obtained through your procedure can also be obtained as $\sin(\pi x)\left(\frac{h(x)}{\sin(\pi x)}g(x)\right)$ in Théophile's procedure.

Comment: Maybe some explanation about _why_ you care about any such function would give a clue about what other properties the function should have. Otherwise why not $g(x) \sin(\pi x)$ for any function $g(x)$ whatsoever, or even $g(x) I_{x\not\in \mathbb Z}$, since you do not say the function has to be non-zero when $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: @DavidK Okay, I have since edited the question in order for it to be more specific, and more in line with what I was thinking about. Please review the question as I have currently framed it. If it needs to be more specific, just let me know, I can add further restrictions.

Comment: @KaR1367: Your conditions definitely make sense and I'm interested to see the options. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Hint: You can build yet another function with this property by using the cosine. $\pi z$ in the argument of the sine function gives you the property you are looking for. What argument would do the same for cosine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the added restrictions, the problem is no longer too wide open.

You already have $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$, of course.
In fact, anything of the form $f(x) = \sin(n\pi x),$
where $n$ is an integer, will do the trick.

You can combine several of these functions together to obtain
different repeating patterns. Try $f(x) = \sin(\pi x) + \sin(3\pi x)$,
for example.

These functions so far are all *odd* functions, meaning you can rotate
them $180$ degrees around the origin and end up with the same function.
In a sense, these functions have "equal" parts above and below the
$x$-axis.
But you can have a function that never goes below the $x$-axis at all,
such as $f(x) = \sin^2(\pi x)$.
You can also have a function that has larger excursions above the axis
than below, such as 
$f(x) = \frac12 + \sin\left(\pi \left(2x - \frac16\right)\right)$.

An example of a non-periodic function would be
$f(x) = \sin(\pi x^2)$.
You can also try $f(x) = \sin\left(\frac12\pi (x^2 + x)\right)$.

As suggested in comments, once you have a function that satisfies the
requirements, you can multiply it by a non-trivial, continuous,
differentiable function to obtain a new function that satisfies the requirements.
For example, $x \sin(\pi x)$ or $x^2 \sin(\pi x)$ both have larger and
larger oscillations as you go farther from $x= 0$.
But $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\sin(\pi x)$ has smaller and smaller oscillations
as you go farther from $x = 0$,
and $e^x \sin(\pi x)$ shrinks in one direction and grows in the other.

Functions such as $\sin^2(\pi x)$, which not only are zero at each
integer value of $x$ but also have zero derivative at each such point,
can be multiplied by functions that are discontinuous (but bounded)
at the integers and still produce a continuous, differentiable function.
But you might find that introducing the discontinuous factor
makes your product function a little harder to work with.

It's a bit challenging to think of any such function that is not
somehow based on sinusoidal functions (sine or cosine),
because we want the building blocks of the functions to be selected
from a fairly limited set, and there are not a lot of functions in
that set that keep returning to zero.
One example is
$$ f(x) = 16 \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor\right)^2
                \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor - 1\right)^2, $$

which looks almost as if it might be sinusoidal, but is not, or
$$ f(x) = 16 \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor\right)^4
                \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor - 1\right)^2, $$
which looks even stranger.
But while these functions satisfy the criteria (including
continuity and differentiability), the discontinuous building blocks
might make them harder to work with than you would like.

If you want to have some fun, start putting these formulas into a decent
graphing calculator or one of the on-line graphing calculators
such as desmos.com. Mix and match, multiply functions by each other,
and so forth, and see what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

As an obvious example, $$f_\gamma(z)=\inf_{k\in\Bbb Z}|z-k|^\gamma$$ for $\gamma>0$.

This question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Here's three:

$$
f(z) = z - [z]\\
f(z) = z - \lfloor z\rfloor\\
f(z) = z - \lceil z \rceil
$$